# How to get started with angular2-material? Failing to npm install

Tags: angular

I am trying to follow:
https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md

Though I keep getting hung up on the initial npm install:

```
npm install --save @angular2-material/core @angular2-material/button @angular2-material/card
```

npm WARN @angular2-material/core@2.0.0-alpha.7-4 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0-rc.5 but none was installed.

@angular2-material/core@2.0.0-alpha.7-4 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0-rc.5 but none was installed.

How can I get around this? Nothing it getting installed...

Comment: what version of angular you are using?

Comment: angular2, set up from the same instructions:  npm install -g angular-cli,  ng new my-project

Comment: ok i'm not using angular-cli and i'm able to install material in angular2.0.0-5rc.

Comment: are you running the npm install command from within the project?

Comment: Yes, I cd'ed into the directory to execute the npm install command referenced in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

npm WARN @angular2-material/core@2.0.0-alpha.7-4 ***requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0-rc.5 but none was installed.***
It require a higher version of angular and i thing you have something below that. upgrading to latest should resolve your problem. you can look into package.json what version you are getting with angular-cli and if it is not latest just hack it and update to latest.

Comment: Is there a way to execute a command to update angular from within the newly created app even though it may be out of date?

Comment: yes npm update but there is a issue with that command ant it's registered on github npm issues. It will update but it will not save to package.json means you get the latest version angular but package.json will not be updated. i suggest you just update the package.json and run npm i. Change to
 "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",

Comment: Thank you! Getting a: pm WARN @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.5 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.5 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router@3.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed. As a side note, do you think angular2 is immature to use for production given its current rc status and problems like these?

Comment: Not angular2 but angular-cli is. Angular-cli came much later and still under development. But this warning has nothing to do with angular itself, It just say that angular-material is built on the higher version and implementing in old version it will not work.

Comment: Okay, I got it installed, as it turned out, rxjs@5.0.0-beta.11 was out... but angular/core@2.0.0-rc.5 refused to install due to not supporting the latest rxjs beta.... this seems silly...

Comment: When attempting to use it via ng serve, am getting: GET http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular2-material/button 404 (Not Found)

Comment: as i told you i don't work with angular-cli because it's still immature so created my on seed which work much better with all setups. [Here it is](https://github.com/blinfo/angular2-webpack-seed) feel free to clone it and lab with it.